# Converting raw sql query to knex

Tags: sql, knex.js

I have a raw query that retrieves specific data from my db which is I want to retrieve `payment_status` success or `payment_type` is bank and `status` is 2.

This is the query which I want to convert to knex.

```
SELECT users.name, 
    users.company, 
    member_trans.amount, 
FROM transactions
RIGHT JOIN 
users ON transactions.payer_dn = users.displayno 
WHERE 
users.account_number = '123456A'
AND (transactions.payment_result = 'Success' 
OR (transactions.payment_type = 'bank' AND transactions.status = 2))
```

This is what I have now, but it is not showing my desired result.

```
return this.knex('transactions')
        .select(
            'users.name', 
            'users.company_name', 
            'transactions.amount',    
        )
        .rightJoin('users','transactions.payer_dn', 'users.displayno')
        .where('users.account_number', '123456A')
        .andWhere(function(){
            this.where('transactions.payment_result', 'Success' )
            .orWhere({'transactions.payment_type':'bank','transactions.status': 2})
        })
```

I believe, there's something affecting my query in the `.andWhere(function(){` clause.
I'm sorry about this one, I'm still practicing knex as of the moment.

Comment: Also, if you have a "current result" that does not match your "expected result" you should include those results in your question. Ideally you would [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: (see sql) `member_trans.amount`  I guess is actually  `transactions.amount` (see knex)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your anyWhere function to:

```
.andWhere(function() {
  this.where(function() {
    this.where('transactions.payment_result', 'Success')
  })
  .orWhere(function() {
    this.where('transactions.payment_type', 'bank')
      .andWhere('transactions.status', 2)
  })
})
```

Comment: Hi. I appreciate your help, but unfortunately, the sql query that I have returns 6 results but what you have provided, it returns 8.

Answer (score 0):

As a "general rule" right joins are just a cause of confusion and I'd recommend you avoid them. With this in mind you can just reverse the table references and use an inner join. Whilst I can't see any Particular issue with the knex in the question, perhaps try this.

```
knex.select('users.name', 'users.company', 'transactions.amount')
    .from('users')
    .innerJoin('transactions', 'transactions.payer_dn', 'users.displayno')
    .where('users.account_number', '=', '123456A')
    .andWhere(function() {
        this.where('transactions.payment_result', '=', 'Success')
            .orWhere(function() {
                this.where('transactions.payment_type', '=', 'bank')
                    .andWhere('transactions.status', '=', 2)
            })
    })
```

for sample sql see: https://dbfiddle.uk/7kAHWZ4J